# How web.config is validated

Tags: asp.net, xml, xsd, web-config

All,This question may be ignored everyday by us asp.net developer like air. If you think it is dumb, Please don't laugh. Thanks,

We knew the `web.config` is hosted in every Asp.Net web application. And It's syntax is restricted by the xml and [DotNetConfig.xsd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255821.aspx). The schema will describe what can be allowed in the `web.config`.

But When we look in a specified `web.config`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
....
</configuration>
```

We didn't see any place to show this xml is based on the `DotNetConfig.xsd`.I mean any xml need to be validated should be documented which schema it is from
So that It can be validated in the runtime. Is that right ?

How does the validation works ? Could someone please tell me something about it . 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`web.config` is *not* strictly validated against the XSD file at runtime. The XSD file is used by Visual Studio as an assistance to developers to avoid typos and other errors in known parts of the configuration file, however because .NET configuration is entirely extensible there is little point in performing XSD-based validation at runtime.

Some validation is performed by `System.Configuration` classes in the class library when they load configuration data, however per-element validation (in this sense) is the responsibility of the consuming configuration classes rather than the web.config loader/parser itself.

Comment: I can see the child elements of `configuration` could be `Any`. So that is what you mean `entirely extensible` in your post . right ? thanks.